# no rule to make target 'Main.o', needed by 'Main' . Stop

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, makefile, game-development

**Note: Unlike other Questions, this one is missing an obj file instead of a cpp file**

I have a Directory called /Profiler
that got the following files:

- Main.cpp
- Draw.cpp
- Draw.h (used in both cpp files)
- Makefile

I created the following Makefile:

```
CC := g++
CCOPTS=-Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++17

Main_DEP_OBJ := Main.o Draw.o
Header:=Draw.h

all: main

%.o: %.C DEPS $(Header)
    $(CC) ${CCOPTS} -c -o $@ $<

Main: $(Main_DEP_OBJ)
    ${CC} ${CCOPTS} -o main $^

clean:
    rm -f Main *.o
```

using the `make` command in Ubuntu gives me this error:

`no rule to make target 'Main.o', needed by 'Main' . Stop.`

Comment: Make sure the indentation is tab characters and not spaces.

Comment: yeah already checked that before posting the Q I thought it's an indentation problem, but that's not it.

Comment: The makefile you posted does not contain a `Main` target, thus it would output a completely different error if you tried to build it (it would output `no rule to make target 'main' needed by 'all' . Stop`.   So you're make is either not using this makefile, or you truncated something from the makefile.   In any case a `%.o : %.cpp ` pattern rule would fix your problem, so long as the makefile can see Main.c.

Answer (score 2):

You dont have a target rule for Main, or building .o file from the .cpp  file.

```
CC := g++
CCOPTS=-Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c++17

Main_DEP_OBJ := Main.o Draw.o
Header:=Draw.h

all: Main 

%.o: %.cpp $(Header)
    $(CC) ${CCOPTS}  -c -o $@  $<

Main: $(Main_DEP_OBJ)
    ${CC} ${CCOPTS} -o Main $^

clean:
    rm -f Main *.o
```

Comment: Are the files and the makefile text capitalized as shown above ?

Comment: works for me assuming files are capitalized as per your question and my makefile

Comment: yes indeed, they are all capitalized (exactly like the Makefile & how I showed in thee Q)

Comment: @ShifraSec maybe you can update the question with your updated makefile changes *and* show us the output of `ls` so we can see exactly the files. Have you got `.cpp` in your rule and not `.CPP` (in your original post you had the wrong file type and the wrong case)

Comment: Is there any other files as well? Perhaps a makefile in lowercase ?